# Using Delphi DLL with dynamic array from C#

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

I have a Delphi DLL that contains the following types:

```
type
  TStepModeType = (smSingle, smMultiStep);

  TParameter = record
    Number: Integer;
  end;

  TStruct = record
    ModType: PAnsiChar;
    ModTypeRev: Integer;
    ModTypeID: Integer;
    RecipeName: PAnsiChar;
    RecipeID: Double;
    RootParamCount: Integer;
    StepMode: TStepModeType;
    ParamCount: Integer;
    Parameters: array of TParameter;
  end;
```

I need to call this DLL from C# passing a ref object corresponding to the Delphi types that the DLL will fill and return.  I have defined structures in my C# code like this:

```
enum stepModeType
{
    Single,
    MultiStep
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct parameter
{
    public int Number;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct recipe
{
    public string modType;
    public int modTypeRev;
    public int modTypeId;
    public string recipeName;
    public double recipeId;
    public int rootParamCount;
    public stepModeType stepMode;
    public int paramCount;
    public IntPtr parameters;
}
```

I was doing fine until I ran into the dynamic array (Parameters: array of TParameter) in the Delphi code.  I understand that dynamic arrays are a Delphi only construct, so I chose to use an IntPtr in my C# code in the hopes of just getting a pointer to the array and pulling the contents.  Unfortunately, I am rather new to this interop stuff and I am not sure how to deal with the IntPtr.

Let's say the Delphi DLL populates the dynamic array with 2 parameter items.  Can someone possibly show me the C# code that would get those 2 parameter items out of the array once it gets passed back from the Delphi DLL to my C# calling application?

UPDATE: Well, as it happens the Delphi code I was given was a simplified version.  One of our Delphi developers thought it would be easier to get started with the simplified version than the real version, which is substantially more complex containing dynamic arrays of dynamic arrays of dynamic arrays.  Anyway, I am now completely over my head.  I only know enough about Delphi to be dangerous.  Below is the code for the real structures in the Delphi code.  Any further guidance on how to deal with these structures from my C# calling application would be greatly appreciated.  It may not even be possible with the nesting of dynamic arrays such that they are.

```
type
  TStepModeType = (smSingle, smMultiStep);

  TParamValue = record
    strVal: String;
    fVal: Double;
    Changed: Boolean;
  end;

  TSteps = array of TParamValue;

  TRule = record
    Value: String;
    TargetEnabled: Boolean;
  end;

  TParamInfo = record
    Caption: String;
    Units: String;
    RuleCount: Integer;
    Rules: array of TRule;
  end;

  TParameter = record
    Info: TParamInfo;
    Steps: TSteps;
  end;

  TStruct = record
    ModType: PAnsiChar;
    ModTypeRev: Integer;
    ModTypeID: Integer;
    RecipeName: PAnsiChar;
    RecipeID: Double;
    RootParamCount: Integer;
    StepMode: TStepModeType;
    ParamCount: Integer;
    Parameters: array of TParameter;
  end;
```

Comment: Does the Delphi DLL contain a function to deallocate the dynamic memory in the struct?

Comment: It does, but as pointed out in your answer I was still using the string fields incorrectly which would have caused a memory issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming trust that the DLL has a function that deallocates the `recipe` struct. That's something that you can't possibly hope to do from C#. More on this point later on.

A Delphi dynamic array is not a valid interop type. It really should only used internally to Delphi code compiled with a single version of the compiler. Exposing it publically is akin to exporting C++ classes from a DLL.

In an ideal world you would re-work the Delphi code so that it exported the array using a proper interop type. However, in this case it is actually relatively easy for you to do the marshalling without adjusting the Delphi code.

Delphi dynamic arrays were introduced way back in Delphi 4 and their implementation has remained unchanged since then. The `array of T` dynamic array variable is effectively a pointer to the first element. The elements are laid out sequentially in memory. The dynamic array variable also maintains (at negative offsets) a reference count and the size of the array. You can safely ignore these since you are neither modifying the dynamic array nor needing to ascertain its size.

Using `IntPtr` for the `Parameters` field is perfect. Because `TParameter` contains just a single 32 bit integer you can use `Marshal.Copy` to copy it straight to an `int[]` array.

So, when the Delphi DLL returns, you can do the final marshalling step using [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146635.aspx).

```
if (theRecipe.paramCount>0)
{
    int[] parameters = new int[theRecipe.paramCount];
    Marshal.Copy(theRecipe.parameters, parameters, 0, theRecipe.paramCount);
    ... do something with parameters
}
```

---

That deals with the dynamic array, but as it happens you have another problem with your code as it stands. You are declaring the two strings as `string` in the C# struct. This means that the marshaller will take responsibility for freeing the memory returned by the Delphi DLL in the two `PAnsiChar` fields. It will do so by calling `CoTaskMemFree`. I'm fairly sure that's not going to match the allocation of the `PAnsiChar` fields made in the Delphi code.

As stated above, I would expect that the contract for this interface is that you call a further DLL function to deallocate the heap memory referenced by the `recipe` struct. That is, the two strings, and the dynamic array.

To deal with this issue from C# you need to make sure that the marshaller does not attempt to deallocate the `PAnsiChar` fields. You can achieve that by declaring them as `IntPtr` in the C# struct. Then call [`Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx) to convert to a C# string.

---

I've had to make a few assumptions about the contract between the Delphi code and the C# code in order to write the above. If any of my assumptions are incorrect please update the question and I'll try to make this answer match! I hope this helps.

Comment: Absolutely perfect!  Thanks so much.  And thanks also for catching the memory issue in the current code.  There is another DLL function to free the memory for the recipe struct, but I was clearly using the string type incorrectly in my C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Jargon confusion I suspect, my first thought was simply.

public parameter[] parameters;

Comment: Thats what I thought at first, but it doesn't work.  If I change the Delphi code to use a statically sized array instead of dynamic, that code works perfectly.  As long as the Delphi array is dynamically sized, I get garbage back for the parameters.

Comment: Looks like someone cleverer than me has sussed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two options: Either you figure out exactly how dynamic arrays are stored and match that on the c# side or better still create a set of basic methods on the Delphi side that can be called from the c# side to manipulate the array and record, eg getItem and setItem etc. That's usually what is done when there are incompatible types across a language barrier. I would use the later approach because you don't know whether at some point in the future the memory structure of a dynamic array might change.

By the way, why have you defined TParameter as a record, you could have used TParameter = integer ?

I found this link which has something to say about the structure of Delphi dynamic arrays:

http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/delphikylix/262971/262971/dynamic-array-memory-storage/

And this link has even more details. The structure is a bit more complicated than a simple array.

[Dynamic Array Structure](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devcommon/internaldataformats_xml.html#44796E616D6963204172726179205479706573)

Comment: I actually didn't write the Delphi code.  I inherited it from a legacy project that I need to interface with from my C# application.  I believe the TParameter object at one time contained much more.  I was asked to attempt to interface with the Delphi code without changing it.  That is why is was looking for a way to handle the dynamic array as is.  I have a very simple solution, write a wrapper class around the Delphi code and convert the dynamic arrays to static arrays before sending back to calling application.  I was hoping to not have to do this, though.

Comment: Ok I see, you're stuck with a previous design. I saw the answer from Heffernan and that should work. I've interfaced fairly complicated interfaces between Delphi and C# including callbacks, you just have to be careful to get the marshaling right.